# Wrap string inside single quotes

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to wrap all individual values which are inside curly braces `{}` using single quotes `' '`.

example:

```
some test {Value1,Value2} more text {Value3} more text {Value4, Value1, Value5, Value9, Value11, Value21}

Above should convert as below:
some test {'Value1','Value2'} more text {'Value3'} more text {'Value4', 'Value1', 'Value5', 'Value9', 'Value11', 'Value21'}
```

I am able to figure out the pattern but not sure how to replace them in file.

Source file content:

```
2321232~CD IN ('JSS12QQ','OQJS','QE9QAA','HAHSS31A','KAA43A','QA00A')~CD IN 
(JSS12QQ','OQJS','ULOE9Q','HAHSS31A','KAA43A','QA00A','QM34AA','WS2A','JS3QQ')~US~
{QA00A,WS2A,JS3QQ,OQJS,KAA43A,ULOE9Q,QM34AA,HAHSS31A,JSS12QQ}~{KAA43A,QA00A,QM34AA,WS2A,JS3QQ}
~CD IN ('2AA2Q')~CD IN ('2AA2Q')~US~{2AA2Q}~{2AA2Q}~{QM34AA,JSS12QQ}
```

Target files content:

```
2321232~CD IN ('JSS12QQ','OQJS','QE9QAA','HAHSS31A','KAA43A','QA00A')~CD IN 
(JSS12QQ','OQJS','ULOE9Q','HAHSS31A','KAA43A','QA00A','QM34AA','WS2A','JS3QQ')~US~
{'QA00A','WS2A','JS3QQ','OQJS','KAA43A','ULOE9Q','QM34AA','HAHSS31A','JSS12QQ'}~{'KAA43A','QA00A','QM34AA','WS2A','JS3QQ'}
~CD IN ('2AA2Q')~CD IN ('2AA2Q')~US~{'2AA2Q'}~{'2AA2Q'}~{'QM34AA,JSS12QQ'}
```

Code to fetch the pattern:

```
import re

def parse(file_name):
        file = open(file_name)
        file_contents =file.read()
        f = file_contents
        rec=re.findall(r"{.*?}",f)
        print (rec)

parse("rule_engine_temp.csv")
```

Please help with explanation so that i can understand and handle its variations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
import re
f="some test {Value1,Value2} more text {Value3} more text {Value4, Value1, Value5, Value9, Value11, Value21}"
rec=re.sub(r"{([^{}]*)}", lambda x: "{{'{}'}}".format("', '".join(re.split(r'\s*,\s*', x.group(1)))) ,f)
print(rec)
# => some test {'Value1', 'Value2'} more text {'Value3'} more text {'Value4', 'Value1', 'Value5', 'Value9', 'Value11', 'Value21'}
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/pNVt11)

Notes:

- `{([^{}]*)}` - matches `{`, then captures 0+ chars other than `{` and `}` into Group 1, and then matches a `}`.
- `re.sub` passes the match data object to a lambda expression
- the Group 1 value is split with `\s*,\s*` - a comma enclosed with optional whitespaces (you may a string split operation if the spacing is consistent, something like `x.group(1).split(',')`) and then joined with `', '`.

Answer (score 2):

My attempt

```
s = """some test {Value1,Value2} more text {Value3} more text {Value4, Value1, Value5, Value9, Value11, Value21}"""

import re

def my_sub(g):
    return '{' + re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z\d]+[a-z\d]+)(,|$)', r"'\1'\2", g[1]) + '}'

s = re.sub(r'{([^{}]+)}', my_sub, s)
print(s)
```

The `r'{([^{}]+)}'` matches the string inside braces ([online demo here](https://regex101.com/r/LjFpXr/3))

Then the sub calls function `my_sub` where we will add commas to values ([online demo here](https://regex101.com/r/LjFpXr/4)).

Comment: Could you explain why you suggest using `(?(id/name)yes-pattern|no-pattern)` here? `({)` is obligatory, so Group 1 will always be matched, `?(1)` will always return TRUE. BTW, if you turn `(?:,|$)` into a capturing group, you may use `r"'\1'\2"` replacement, and would not need `rstrip(',')`. You may also use a more efficient lookahead here, `(?=,|$)` or even a better one, `(?![^,])`, and use `r"'\1'"` replacement.

Comment: If you want to obfuscate a regex :), here is another idea: [`((?![a-zA-Z0-9-])[\u007B])(.*?)(?(1)(?![\u007C\u007E])[|-~])`](https://regex101.com/r/beoNiI/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, you have right, Its quite obfuscated ;) I quickly read the re module docs and thought that this is the way to match braces, but simple `{([^{}]+)}` would be enough. Still learning the `re`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I edited my answer. Thanks for the suggestion about the removing the `rstrip()`!